# How can I INSERT into a MySQL table in Python with a variable number of columns?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a variable `row_data = (searchindex, asin, title, browsenode, salesrank, brand, listprice, saleprice)` and either of those elements might be `NULL`, to insert into a database, I'm using

```
sql = "INSERT INTO table (searchindex,asin,title,browsenode, salesrank, brand, listprice, saleprice) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s', '%s', '%s', '%f', '%f')" % row_data
```

But that's not very scalable as I add more fields into row_data. Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: "But that's not very scalable as I add more fields into row_data"?  Really?  How often will you change the schema?  Every few seconds?  Or once a month?

Comment: It's hard to read with all the %s's and %f's so as I develop, it's tough to keep track of

Comment: First, don't use string substitution.  Second, get an ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't use string interpolation to construct SQL, as it is very unsafe. Use the appropriate features in your MySQL library to pass in the values as parameters to the query.

The number of columns in a table should hardly change as your program is developed. Maybe once every few months, at which point it's rarely difficult to update your SQL.

Alternatively you could use a system such as [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) which handles a lot of this for you and stops you having to write much SQL yourself.

Comment: What are the features in MySQLd?